# How to find the dimensions of an SVG image so that there is no white space around the graphics and the text remains readable?

Tags: c#, svg

I process C++ generated SVG images which are generated to given pixel width and height.

How do I C#-determine the optimal width and height dimensions for displaying the SVG images so that there is not much white space / margin around the image and the text in the images remains readable?

That is if I specify the font size for the image and redraw the image, how do I determine the target optimal dimensions in pixel guaranteeing the text is in the given font size and there is not too much white space around the image?

Comment: You really can't unless the tool that is creating the image has settings.  The best you can do is set the ration between height and width but that may crop part of the text.

Comment: Thanks, @jdweng. I can pass to the C++ code the width & height in pixels but that's all. 

I was thinking about this - I will render the svg in a bitmap canvas and then find the first top-left / top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right -black pixel, essentially identifying the rectangle. Then, I somehow take into account the font size and calculate the right dimensions.

Comment: If you are generating the SVG, you presumably have all the coordinates that are being used.  Just build a bounding box of all points as you go.  If you account for every point, corner, radius, bezier control point, etc, you will have something that is close to an optimal viewBox. It might be a bit large, but it will be a pretty good approximation. The only tricky issue is dealing with path arc (A/a) commands. You might want to avoid them. :)